# When I save the CSV and edit it again the columns merged

Tags: excel, csv, utf-8, ms-office

I created a CSV file and I saved it as (CSV UTF8 Comma delimited) but I got message

> Some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited). Do you want to keep using the format?

[image]
I clicked Yes and save the CSV, then I open it again and doing edits when I save it no message appear. but when I open it again the columns merged in one column (as I think the comma removed by somehow!). So what is the issue here??

Before Save

[image]

After Save, close, then open it again
[image]

**NOTE: I'm using Office 2016**

Comment: Open the CSV file with Notepad and check what's the separator character. Do that again after editing with Excel. Has it changed? What's the list separator in your computer's regional settings? Does it make a difference if you don't use Arab characters?

Comment: After the first save it separated by   a comma , .. after the second save I open it I didn't see a separator, just space

Comment: What's the list separator in your computer's regional settings? Does it make a difference if you don't use Arab characters?

Comment: @Andrew English United States

Comment: You are replying half of my questions each time.

Comment: sorry Andrew I miss understand you, but Eric's answer solve the issue. Also when I edit the file in notepad and adding comma manually it works too! but may hard to control and edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel has some difficulty understanding how to merge complex codesets (English ASCII and Arabic UTF-8). You have to give it some help. This is not very fun.

We have an exported file csv (the c stands for comma, but really it can be another character)
Open Excel
Select Data - Import External Data - Import Data
Select the file type as csv
select your file
In the Import Wizard change the File origin as 65001 UTF (basically choose the  language identifier you need)
Change the Delimiter to comma (or whatever you want to use)
Import

Comment: I use Office 365. This worked for me.

Write or copy from a file that correctly displays Arabic (right to left, correct alphabet).

Open a new notebook.

Paste your Arabic in the second column. Do this first.

Type your English in the first column. 

I exported and opened the file on my machine. The formatting was fine. I opened that exported copy in Office 365 and that was also fine. 

If you use the desktop version, this should be easier. Columns can be formatted. A simple example is here

https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html

Comment: This happens to me with straight English, complex codesets don't even come into play.  This bug bites me time and time again, and I can't believe a bug like this exists in a product of this level.  Microsoft has seriously disappointed me this year (this is just a small portion of all of the bugs I'm constantly jumping through hoops to get around across their entire suite of everything).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the save shortcut - use save as instead.  I've found it's saving as unicode and you have to switch it to save as a CSV again.